# Mapping two identical enumeration with different namespaces

Tags: c#, parsing, enums, type-conversion

I've two identical C# enumeration defined like these:

```
public enum ArrivalToleranceEnum
{
    ZERO,
    QUARTERHOUR,
    HALFHOUR,
    ONEHOUR,
    TWOHOURS,
}

public enum ArrivalTolerance {

    /// <remarks/>
    ZERO,

    /// <remarks/>
    QUARTERHOUR,

    /// <remarks/>
    HALFHOUR,

    /// <remarks/>
    ONEHOUR,

    /// <remarks/>
    TWOHOURS,
}
```

ArrivalTolerance is defined in an external library and in my program I want to use a local enumaration ArrivalToleranceEnum so I need to convert these two types. How can I do this? I've tried to do this by end (using a switch) but it's very tedius and not very time saving because I've other much bigger enumeration I need to convert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enum values are represented by integer constants. **If the underlying enum constants are the same**, just cast:

```
(ArrivalToleranceEnum)(int)ArrivalTolerance.HALFHOUR
```

If they are not the same, you can automate the mapping using reflection code or one of the static members of the `Enum` class. That is more tedious and much slower, though.

Comment: You are assuming that order of enums is the same

Comment: @wudzik I'm calling that out in the answer explicitly. If they are not the same, you can use string or reflection-based methods like given in the answer.

Comment: @usr not if the constants are the same, but order is same :) but for sure this will work for example in this question

Comment: @wudzik enums do not have order at the CLR level. C# uses the order to assign integer constants.

Comment: @usr I mean order in code which should affect in int values of enum value

Comment: The order issue is orthogonal. It affects the values but only the values matter. The following two enums are compatible: `{ A = 1, B = 2 }` and `{ B = 2, A = 1 }`. The values are the determining factor. Anything that determines values of course also affects compatibility. But that does not go the other way around, as shown by the example.

Comment: @usr What wudzik says is that `{ A, B }` and `{ B, A }` won't be "compatible" with the integer comparison.

Comment: @wudzik he said `not if the constants are the same, but order is same` which is wrong because is says that same order implies compatibility. That's wrong. "Compatibility" is exactly equal to "name-value-pairs being equal". "Compatibility" is different from "order being equal". Therefore his definition is incomplete/wrong.

Answer (score 7):

If only names match, not order use this

```
var value = Enum.Parse(typeof(ArrivalToleranceEnum),ArrivalTolerance.ToString());
```

If you don't sure that int values of all enums are match it's better to use string matching solution.

Answer (score 1):

a enumeration is a subset of `int`  type, you can do like this:

```
ArrivalToleranceEnum ext;
ArrivalTolerance your_enum=(ArrivalTolerance)((int)ext);
```

the solution suggested by wudzik is the safest if the name are the same.

You can also specify the int value to be associated to each enum, for example `HALFHOUR=0,`

Answer (score 1):

If order match, you can directly cast it : `(ArrivalToleranceEnum)ArrivalTolerance.ZERO`

However if the mapping should be more specific, i would recommend using a `Dictionary<ArrivalTolerance,ArrivalToleranceEnum>`, because it is much faster than using `Enum.Parse`.